# Recurse massive dir structure, delete files over X days

Tags: recursive, delete

First linux coding job.

Told to make a script for a chron job that
dives through all folders on server and  deletes any files over X days (probably 20).

I have tested the code below on my home Redhat box.

Of course I have many trepidations before I promote this code to actual usage.
Code below works fine, BUT I also need it to delete ONLY files (and NOT directories) OVER "X" number of days.

Cannot download, make any modifications to the system of hundreds of directories and  thousands of files. 
The first time I run this, I expect to delete over 10,000 files, as our clients leave their files on our servers and forget about them.  (This will wake them up!)

I tried changing line five, 
"elif [ -f  "$i" *-a -mtime +21* ]; then"
-remove file (rm -i "$1")

Doesn't work, saying
"[: mtime: binary operator expected"

Do I need another elif statement, or can I make the selection criteria (files only and just those over "X" days) work on one line?

CODE:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash 

print_folder_recurse() {
    for i in "$1"/*; do
        if [ -d "$i" ]; then
            print_folder_recurse "$i"
        elif [ -f  "$i" ]; then
            rm -i  $i #(put the -i in there for #testing, it will be removed)
        fi    
    done
}
```

path "/go/to/your/happy/place"

```bsh
echo "Delete path: $path"
print_folder_recurse $path
```

Thank you.

Comment: Or use the systemd tool that's built for the job...

Comment: You are using `$1` and `$i` in the same script. What is the `$i` about? Does it work (better) if you switch to using `$1` consistently?

Comment: @linux-fan I believe doing that would cause an infinite loop

Comment: Thanks, I see it now :)

Answer (score 1):

```
find /your/directory -type f -daystart -mtime +20 -delete
```

Remove the `-delete` to perform a dry run.

Comment: Excellent answer. but I am now  informed, if there is only one file in the directory, do not delete it. (please don't ask me why).

Comment: I'm thinking to do some kind of find . -type f | wc -l >dirs.txt, sort it, and then read in only those directories with multiple files using  some kind of xargs into the statement above?

Comment: That’s a different, more difficult question. Given that the parameters are significantly different, please ask a new question.

Comment: Thanx.Will do.     Gonna hack at it for a while first.